# Autodetect JRE Version and Install the required Version on MAC OS X before launching an application

Tags: macos, java

Autodetect JRE Version and Install the required Version on MAC OS X before launching an application.How?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) ? It allows you to package your Java solution with an installer that can detect JREs and launch an installer for that particular JRE if necessary.

Note that the website says Launch4J is for Windows, but the changelog indicates that a Mac OS X version has been available for some time (and available in the [downloads](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=95944&package_id=192323))