# Can't launch app on Mac OS X I receive error LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application with error -10810

Tags: java, macos, runtime

### The Problem

I am trying to launch an app ([Genetic Network Analyzer](http://www.genostar.com/category/products/gna/)) but it fails silently. When using `open gna.app` the following error message is produced:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/GNA_8.7.1.1/gna.app
```

I believe the issue has to do with my Java Run time Environment (the program is written in Java). I do not know how to correct this issue.

### Technical Stuff:

- My operating system is Mac OS X version
- I have both the latest version of Java, Java 8 Update 91
- I have also installed [legacy Java](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US)
- The info.plist file for the app

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE plist SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/PropertyList.dtd">
  <plist version="0.9">
  <dict>
  <key>CFBundleName</key>
  <string>gna</string>
  <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
  <string>JavaApplicationStub</string>
  <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
  <string>app.icns</string>
  <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
  <string>6.0</string>
  <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
  <string>APPL</string>
  <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
  <string>????</string>
  <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
  <string>com.install4j.7878-5124-9390-0704.96</string>
  <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
  <string>8.7.1.1</string>
  <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
  <string>8.7.1.1</string>
  <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
  <string>8.7.1.1</string>
  <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
  <string>en</string>
  <key>CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations</key>
  <true/>
  <key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
  <true/>
  <!-- I4J_INSERT_DOCTYPE -->
  <key>i4j.baseDir</key>
  <string>$APP_PACKAGE/../</string>
  <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
  <string>10.7.3</string>
  <key>i4j.appId</key>
  <string>7878-5124-9390-0704</string>
  <key>i4j.allowPassthrough</key>
  <true/>
  <key>i4j.minVersion</key>
  <string>1.7</string>
  <key>i4j.maxVersion</key>
  <string>1.7</string>
  <key>i4j.vmIdPrefix</key>
  <string></string>
  <key>JavaVM</key>
  <dict>
  <key>MainClass</key>
  <string>com.install4j.runtime.launcher.MacLauncher</string>
  <key>VMOptionArray</key>
  <array>
  <string>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</string>
  <string>-Diogma.home=$APP_PACKAGE/..</string>
  <string>-Diogma.user.home=$APP_PACKAGE/..</string>
  <string>-Diogma.user.externals=$APP_PACKAGE/..</string>
  <string>-Diogma.user.data=$APP_PACKAGE/..</string>
  <string>-Diogma.licenser=default</string>
  <string>-Dlog4j.debug</string>
  <string>-Dlog4j.configuration=iogma/platform/log4j.properties</string>
  <string>-Dswing.defaultlaf=net.infonode.gui.laf.InfoNodeLookAndFeel</string>
  <string>-Duser.language=en</string>
  <string>-Diogma.application.name=GNA</string>
  <string>-Diogmadatabase=false</string>
  <string>-Dinstall4j.launcherId=96</string>
  <string>-Dinstall4j.swt=false</string>
  <string>-Djava.library.path=$APP_PACKAGE/../Externals/Ports/x86_64-darwin/lib</string>
  <string>-Dexe4j.moduleName=$APP_PACKAGE</string>
  </array>
  <key>OptionsFile</key>
  <string>$APP_PACKAGE/Contents/vmoptions.txt</string>
  <key>ArgumentArray</key>
  <array>
  </array>
  <key>SplashFile</key>
  <string>$APP_PACKAGE/../.install4j/s_1qq6wu9.png</string>
  <key>JVMVersion</key>
  <string>1.4+</string>
  <key>ClassPath</key>
  <string>$APP_PACKAGE/../.install4j/i4jruntime.jar:$APP_PACKAGE/../bin/*:$APP_PACKAGE/../GNA/bin/*:$APP_PACKAGE/../plugins/iogma.core.platform/bin/*</string><!-- I4J_INSERT_CLASSPATH -->
  </dict>
  </dict>
  </plist>
  ```

### Additional Notes:

- I have also contacted the developer, but this program does work on other computers running Mac OS X 10.11.5.
- I have looked at the following posts and they do not answer my question as they are either for another operating system, they are not trying to launch an app bundle, they are trying to create an program I am not, or the solution does not work for me.

  - [What makes an OS X app not open with the error “LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28105587/what-makes-an-os-x-app-not-open-with-the-error-lsopenurlswithrole-failed-with)
  - [AppBundle throws “LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810” after compiling with java 7 or 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325308/appbundle-throws-lsopenurlswithrole-failed-with-error-10810-after-compiling)
  - [Autodetect JRE Version and Install the required Version on MAC OS X before launching an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038226/autodetect-jre-version-and-install-the-required-version-on-mac-os-x-before-launc)
  - [Install4j - Mac OSX Single Bundle with Java 7 - app launch error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458383/install4j-mac-osx-single-bundle-with-java-7-app-launch-error)
  - [JWrapper example application fails to launch on Mac OS X 10.8.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704118/jwrapper-example-application-fails-to-launch-on-mac-os-x-10-8-5)
- I also do not know how .plist files function so please be aware of that when answering my question.