# Can't open macOS App. What does the + symbol represent in permissions?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am working in terminal on macOS. I have a macOS App with permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 root admin
```

What does the + at the end mean?

There are [similar questions](https://superuser.com/questions/71519/file-permissions-in-unix) to this for other environments.

I can't launch the App. I get this error.

LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /path/to/file

**EDIT1**: I have several user accounts setup. I have used chown to change from userA to root. I hoped this would allow any user to open the App. If I login to 'userA' account, I can launch the App, but if I use any other user account, I get the above error. What the jellybeans is going on ???

**Edit2**: I deleted the App from userA and re-downloaded / installed using userB. userB can launch the app just fine but userA cannot (same error). The user:group is slightly different this time though (notice the '+' isn't there by default this time.

drwxr-xr-x   3 userB  staff

Performing sudo chown root /path/to/file changed the permissions to

drwxr-xr-x   3 root   staff

This made no change i.e. userB can launch and userA cannot.

Comment: `+` signals ACLs, what does `ls -led /path_to_app` produce (`-e` displays ACLs)?

Comment: @ewcz 0: user:robertnash allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130587/lsopenurlswithrole-failed-with-error-10810-downloaded-app-does-not-start

Answer (score 0):

if you can see `+` in the file permission then ACL is setup on the file. It means a special permission has set on the file which allow owner of the file to provide the access to individual. You need to ask to owner of the file to execute below command then you will be able to execute the script/program/app.

```
setfacl -m u:youruserid:rwx file.txt
```

to know more about ACL, check [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/System_Administration_Guide/s1-acls-setting.html).

I Never get the chance to set ACL on mac file but I believe it will work same as it  work in GNU/Linux.

Comment: Thank you @VIPINKUMAR that link was very informative. I have managed to clear the '+' symbol by removing all ACL's for the App. Unofrutnatley, the App still does not launch and I get the same error message. However, this post is specifically addressing the '+' symbol, which is what I originally thought the issue was related to. I will have to post another question regarding this error message.

Comment: Ha, it looks like someone beat me to it. They have had no answer to their post. It looks like this problem won't be solved. I might put my computer in the trash and get a fresh coffee. And maybe take up a new hobby like tennis maybe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37708689/cant-launch-app-on-mac-os-x-i-receive-error-lsopenurlswithrole-failed-for-the